# How to make a div encompass everything

Tags: html, css

I have a program here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvy4cLpc/1/), and I am wondering how I am supposed to make the div go around everything. By going around everything I mean by having the border around everything. (Plus more effective jQuery code would be appreciated ;) .) Here is the code:

```css
div {
    border:2px red outset;
}
div#container {
    width:50%;
}
div.section {
    position:relative;
    width:48%;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
    h3 {
    display:inline;
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    margin:0.65;
    text-align:center;
} a {
    display:inline;
    width:23%;
    float:left;
    margin:0.65%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And my HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>

    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <br />
    <br /> <a href="#sec1" class="hide">Hide</a><a href="#sec1" class="show">Show</a>
    <a href="#sec2" class="hide">Hide</a><a href="#sec2" class="show">Show</a>

    <div id="sec1" class="section">Some content</div>
    <br />
    <div id="sec2" class="section">Some more content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's just collapsing a bit given the children with float - have you tried clearing your container? `#container:after { content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your container div:

```
div#container {
    width:50%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jvy4cLpc/3/)**

When you float the child, the parent essentially shrinks as the floated child is removed from the document flow. Adding the overflow rule restores the layout you expect. And your jQuery seems fine.